# Why is the first verb in this sentence in the present perfect while the second one is in the past simple?

Tags: tense

> He **has toured** the UK, **sold out** three nights at London's Sebright Arms, as well festival performances at Glastonbury,

Can someone explain me why **has toured** is in the present perfect and **sold out** in the past simple? Is it because the UK tour lasted more time   than the sold out three nights or does the author think that the tour was more important than the sold out nights?

There should be a logical reason.

Comment: *Sold out* is in fact present perfect. The ellipsis includes *has*: "He has [toured .. and .. sold .. ]". The conjunction *and* should be there; its omission makes this a 'comma splice'.

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: Maybe it is possible that "sold" is a *past participle* here.

Comment: Is this quote made up?  It doesn't read at all well.  "As well" should definitely be "as well as", but even after that correction, it vwould still be awkward in writing (it might be said in off-the-cuff speech) unless you also inserted "and" before "sold".

Answer (score 1):

The second verb is also in the present perfect. The auxiliary "has" covers all the verbs in the list.

Test it with a verb that has a different past form to its past participle (we use the past participle with "have/has" in the present perfect):

> She has made a cake and eaten it.

not

> She has made a cake and ate it.